# display: none; in media query not working

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries, responsive

```css
.albums .next_album {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.1 );
    box-shadow: 0 8px 32px 0 rgba( 31, 38, 135, 0.37 );
    backdrop-filter: blur( 9.5px );
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur( 9.5px );
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* start media query */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    
    .next_album {
        display: none;
    }

    .albums {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="week_album">
  <h2>Album of the week</h2>
  <div class="albums">
      <div class="single_album">
          <div class="image_album">
              <img src="elm050120fobcover0004a-1585330301.jpg" alt="this is a album">
          </div>
          <h3>Dua Lipa</h3>
          <p>If it ain't me</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single_album">
          <div class="image_album">
              <img src="unnamed.jpg" alt="this is a album">
          </div>
          <h3>Erfan</h3>
          <p>Fargh Dareh</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single_album">
          <div class="image_album">
              <img src="0b66f3ccb36641d285b8e84d7619d5ed.png" alt="this is a album">
          </div>
          <h3>Poobon</h3>
          <p>Tigh</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single_album">
          <div class="image_album">
              <img src="halsey-attends-the-2022-bud-light-super-bowl-music-fest-at-crypto.com-arena-in-los-angeles-100222_5.jpg" alt="this is a album">
          </div>
          <h3>Halsey</h3>
          <p>New Americana</p>
      </div>
      <div class="single_album">
          <div class="image_album">
              <img src="Yas,_Iranian_rapper_live_in_2018_05_(cropped).jpg" alt="this is a album">
          </div>
          <h3>Yas</h3>
          <p>Beem</p>
      </div>
      <div class="next_album">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>  
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a div with class "albums" and some div elements in it. one of them has a class named "next_album", it has `display: flex;`. I want it to be totally removed when the size of window reaches 992px. but the `display: none;` in the media query doesn't work.
can somebode please help me with this?
I'm going crazy.

I need to add that I put another div after next_album for test and I gave that a dsiplay: flex; and a display: none; in the media query part and it worked! I mean it disappeared in 992px or less size of the width.
[this is the adderss of my repository.](https://github.com/yunes2002/Yunes_Song)

Comment: Looks like a specificity issue. Try using `.albums .next_album { display: none; }` in your media query to match the outer rule

Comment: I read that, but no. that is not the answer of my question.

Comment: I don't understand. how is that gonna make a difference ? I already did that in my media query. please explain more @Phil

Comment: _"I already did that in my media query"_... no you haven't. Your media query has only `.next_album` which is **less specific** than `.albums .next_album`. Media queries have no effect on specificity

Comment: @Phil "Media queries have no effect on specificity". I tried what you said and it worked. I have never encountered such a problem before. I gotta say that I don't know what specificity means in css.

Comment: What I mean by that is that you essentially have two rules. One for `.albums .next_album` then `.next_album`. The former is more specific than the latter so it always wins. The media query does not change the specificity of the latter. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity